# Self join with latest earlier date

Tags: sql, database

I have SCD2 data, and I'm trying to establish a relation of each data point to its predecessor.

I'm concerned that what I've come up with so far might be highly inefficient.

```
Select 
  ID,
  ValidFrom,
  ValidTo
from Table as T0
left join Table as T1 
  on T1.ID = T0.ID 
 and T0.ValidFrom>T1.ValidFrom
left join Table as T2 
  on T2.ID = T1.ID 
 and T2.ValidTo > T1.ValidTo 
 and T2.ValidTo < T0.ValidTo
where T2.ID is null
```

Is there a way to do it more performant?

Thank you so much :)

```
Select 
  ID,
  ValidFrom,
  ValidTo
from Table as T0
left join Table as T1 
  on T1.ID = T0.ID 
 and T0.ValidFrom>T1.ValidFrom
left join Table as T2 
  on T2.ID = T1.ID 
 and T2.ValidTo > T1.ValidTo 
 and T2.ValidTo < T0.ValidTo
where T2.ID is null
```

Comment: Hi - I'm not clear what you are doing and why you've repeated what seems to be the same SQL statement? Please could you update your question with sample data for your table and the result you are trying to achieve - with an explanation of how you are achieving that result if it's not obvious?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Most RDBMS feature `ROW_NUMBER` which you can use to number all rows and then join on n = n +1. I suppose the `ID` in your query is not the table's ID, but just some other ID? And the columns you want to select are probably also different from what you are showing. Yes?

Comment: Yes it is just the structure of the table and your assumptions are correct. The ID is the Business Key and no technical ID or something like that. I want to bring attributes from the predesessor to the actual row.  it can be a bunch of attributes and more can come over time. It becomes a view. Since all that is not necessary for the problem i reduced it to the essentials.

Comment: Please read this link for a guide how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, as mentioned, numbering the rows and then self joining on that number is one option. Another is a lateral join where you just join one other row per original row. Or you go with your not-exists approach. Non of these will be really fast, I guess, but an index on the ID and date will probably help a lot. Is it on purpose that you are working sometoimes with the from date and sometimes with the to date? Sticking to one might be faster. If you are thinking of a view, a materialized view might be a solution, if your DBMS features that.

Comment: And please tag your request with your DBMS. SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS i question, so as to only get appropriate answers.